# WooCommerce hook reference for after page redirection

Tags: php, woocommerce, hook

Is there any hook action available to capture the order summary after the payment is successful when redirected to PayPal default payment gateway on WooCommerce? Or if I could even capture it when the order summary page loads, that would be great!

Comment: If **after the payment is successful** is your criteria, then `woocommerce_thankyou` hook will work.

Comment: Does it work after payment redirection?

Comment: Sorry, Thanks man. That worked